# How to show comment via views?

Tags: 7, comments

I have a content type nodes with comments. I need to show latest comment via views. For this I created a views its just showing me comment status. not comment.

Comment: Could you provide an export of your view (there is an 'export' tab for that)?

Answer (score 1):

To create a view of comments for a particular content type, what you have to do is create a new view and select `Comments` in 'Show' select list as shown in the pic : [image]

After that go to `Filter Creteria` section and select the particular content type to which you want to show the comments. Also select the `Comment: Approved(Yes)` filter creteria.[image]